# mdx select top n with crossjoins

Tags: filter, mdx

I want to filter this query and eliminate members where [Measures].[Orders Count] = 1.

The query was generated by an Excel pivot table - all the crossjoins and other syntax has me somewhat confused:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Ticket Avg] as
 [Measures].[Net Amount] / [Measures].[Orders Count]
SELECT NON EMPTY CrossJoin (
 Hierarchize (
  DrilldownMember (
   {
    {
     DrilldownMember (
      {
       {
        DrilldownLevel (
         { [Dates].[Date].[All] }
         ,
         ,
         , INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS
        )
       }
      }
      , { [Dates].[Date].[YYYY].&[2014] }
      ,
      ,
      , INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS
     )
    }
   }
   , { [Dates].[Date].[YYYYPP].&[2014]&[2014P10] }
   ,
   ,
   , INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS
  )
 )
 ,

 { [Measures].[Orders Count], [Measures].[Net Amount], [Measures].[Ticket Avg] }

) DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME
, HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME
, [Dates].[Date].[YYYYPP].[YYYY]
, [Dates].[Date].[YYYYPPW].[YYYYPP]
 ON COLUMNS
, NON EMPTY CrossJoin (
 Hierarchize (
  {
   DrilldownLevel (
    { [Stores].[Market].[All] }
    ,
    ,
    , INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS
   )
  }
 )
 , Hierarchize (
  {
   DrilldownLevel (
    { [Mixes].[Mix].[All] }
    ,
    ,
    , INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS
   )
  }
 )
) DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME
, HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS
FROM (
 SELECT ( { [Dates].[Date].[YYYYPP].&[2014]&[2014P01] } ) ON COLUMNS
 , ( { [Stores].[Market].[Market Region Name].&[CHICAGO] } ) ON ROWS
 FROM [Orders]
)
WHERE ( [Stores].[Corp-Fran-Intl].[Corporate Franchise International].&[Corporate] ) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE
, FORMAT_STRING
, LANGUAGE
, BACK_COLOR
, FORE_COLOR
, FONT_FLAGS
```

Comment: Look into the MDX HAVING clause.

Comment: Do you HAVE to work with this MDX and apply filter or do you have the option to rewrite it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you want the filter on the rows then create a custom `mdx` set using Excel's `mdx` tools. Then you shold be able to just use the named set in the pivot table:

```
{filter(      
Hierarchize (
        DrilldownMember (
          DrilldownMember (
            DrilldownLevel (
             { [Dates].[Date].[All] }
            )
          , { [Dates].[Date].[YYYY].&[2014] }
          )
         , { [Dates].[Date].[YYYYPP].&[2014]&[2014P10] }
       )
      )
,[Measures].[Orders Count] <> 1
)}
```

Or if it is the rows that you'd like to filter your custom set could be either of the following:

```
{filter(
 Hierarchize (
   DrilldownLevel (
    { [Stores].[Market].[All] }
   )
 )
 ,[Measures].[Orders Count] <> 1
 )}
```

..or here...

```
{filter(
 Hierarchize (
   DrilldownLevel (
    [Mixes].[Mix].[All]
   )
 )
 ,[Measures].[Orders Count] <> 1
 )}
```